# composer not loading class after moving folder

Tags: php, class, composer-php

I've got an issue where I moved the whole folder into a server WITH the vendor files and everything, and it's not loading the classes anymore, while the localhost/local copy is working ok. What might be the problem? 
The error code is unnecessary, but I'm adding it anyway..

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Google_Service_Adsense' not found in /home/user/full/path/of/the/file/where/its/located

the files are unchanged, only moved into the server. Composer is not in the server, and it's a managed server so no ability to install and update the package or composer either.

composer.json:

> { "require": { "google/apiclient": "^2.0", "google/apiclient-services": "^0.68.0" } }

filepath where the classfile should reside:

> myDirectory\vendor\google\apiclient-services\src\Google\Service\AdSense.php

the link where it actually resides in the github repo:

https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client-services/blob/master/src/Google/Service/AdSense.php

---

update:
after deleting the whole thing from the server and reimporting I'm getting this error:

`Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/home/user/full/path/of/the/file/where/its/located/vendor/composer/../guzzlehttp/psr7/src/functions_include.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear') in /home/user/full/path/of/the/file/where/its/located/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 66`

---

second update. After removing the directory with the contents from the server once again, uploading a ziped archive, unzipping it I'm still left with the first fatal error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After struggling for more than I should have with different types of file upload and unextraction I manually loaded the file where the class was located (even though I shouldn't need to do that in my opinion )
like:

```
  require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/google/apiclient-services/src/Google/Service/AdSense.php';
```

and it started working.